# Javascript - When creating new audio objects, when are they downloaded?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

In my JS code I create an array with a lot of audio objects. However, in most cases I won't need all the objects. My question is, will the unused audio still be downloaded?

```
  audioArray = [];
  audioURLs = ['url0', 'url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4'];
  for (let i = 0; i < audioURLs.length; i++) {
    audioArray.push(new Audio(audioURLs[i]));
  }
  audioArray[0].play() //For example
```

Will the audio objects 1-4 be downloaded in this case?

Comment: I would recommend using browser's Developer tools' Network tab, then you can be 100% sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) for the `Audio` constructor:

> **Return value**
>
> A new `HTMLAudioElement` object, configured to be used for playing back the audio from the file specified by `url`. The new object's `preload` property is set to `auto` and its `src` property is set to the specified URL or `null` if no URL is given. **If a URL is specified, the browser begins to asynchronously load the media resource before returning the new object.**

*(my emphasis)*

This is covered by the specification [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#concept-media-load-algorithm), which is linked from the spec's description of the legacy `Audio` constructor [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#dom-audio).

> Will the audio objects 1-4 be downloaded in this case?

The browser will begin to asynchronously download the resources from their URLs, yes.